# CSS syntax to select class of an element identified by its id

Tags: css

For this code

```
<div id="dogs" class="content">hello</div>
<div id="frogs" class="content">hello</div>
<div id="hogs" class="content">hello</div>
<div id="logs" class="content">hello</div>
```

How can I select the class `content` from the element that has the id dogs?

Comment: Why can't you just use `#dogs`? There shouldn't be any other element with an ID of "dogs", since IDs must be unique..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```css
.content#dogs {
  font: bold 28px sans-serif;
  color: #800000;
}
```

```html
<div id="dogs" class="content">hello</div>
<div id="frogs" class="content">hello</div>
<div id="hogs" class="content">hello</div>
<div id="logs" class="content">hello</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, just out of curiosity is `.content#dogs` equivalent to `#dogs.content`?